# Retrieve center of QML map in C++

Tags: c++, qt, properties, qml

I've the following QML that shows a map:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtPositioning 5.15
import QtLocation 5

Item {
    width: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.width : 512
    height: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.height : 512
    visible: true
    property double center_latitude: 59.91
    property double center_longitude: 10.75

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(center_latitude, center_longitude)
        zoomLevel: 14
        copyrightsVisible: false
    }
}
```

I set int in a `QQuickWidget` and everything seems ok:

```
m_quickWidget->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/map.qml")));
```

I can see the map correctly. Now I want to retrieve the coordinates of the center of the map, that should be retrieved with the map `center` property. The problem is that I don't know how to access to that property with C++.

I've tried

```
auto mp = m_quickWidget->rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem*>("Map");
auto items = m_quickWidget->rootObject()->childItems();
auto center = mp->property("center").value<QGeoCoordinate>();
extent.setCenter(LLA{ center.latitude(), center. Longitude(), 0.0 });
center = m_quickWidget->rootObject()->property("center").value<QGeoCoordinate>();
```

but `mp` gives me a `nullptr`, while `items` is a vector of only one element, and I don't know how to handle it. The last row gives me a `QGeoCoordiante` with `NaN`, so it's not correct.

How can I retrieve the center from the `QQuickWidget`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findChild()` is searching for items via the [objectName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html#objectName-prop). So you need to add an `objectName` to your `Map`.

```
Map {
    objectName: "testmap"
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
    ...
}
```

and then you can search for it.

```
auto map = view->rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem *>("testmap");
if (map) {
    auto center = map->property("center").value<QGeoCoordinate>();
    qDebug() << map << center;
}
```

The above code returns the following.

```
QDeclarativeGeoMap(0x55fc0d7de000, name="testmap", parent=0x55fc0d746940, geometry=0,0 800x600)
QGeoCoordinate(59.91, 10.75)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck with "id" instead of "objectName".